# How to connect wires from a SNES controller to the Pi Zero's GPIO?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, retropie

I am following a MagPi tutorial [(issue 42, February 2016)](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues/42) showing how to build a HDMI-powered retroconsole by fitting a Raspberry Pi Zero into a SNES controller.

I am unsure how to connect the SNES's controller wires to the Pi Zero's GPIO.
There are 5 wires that I soldered directly to some of the ports, following [this diagram](https://hackaday.io/project/16288/gallery#c279f7baca8afb2dd7acca7aabfc4067):

[image]

Alas, RetroPie does not recognize the controller upon start up.

Two questions here:

1. Is it OK to solder directly the SNES controller wires to the GPIO? If that's the case, is there an additional step to tell the Pi Zero which ports to listen to?
2. Is it possible the solder the 5 wires to a mini-USB connector? Having stripped one of those to connect the Power Boost, I can see that they consist of only 4 different wires...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: it is ok to solder the wires directly ... did you connect the wires to the correct pads? .... how did you determine which wire goes where?

Comment: I naively followed the wiring diagram referenced in my post, although I am not using an actual SNES controller but this ersatz instead: https://www.adafruit.com/product/131